# Python boto force connect to s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

Can anyone help me with connecting to amazon s3. I have next problem:
I want to check whether provided credential are good to connect on step when just creating connection. For example:

```
import boto
boto.connect_s3(access_key,wrong_secret_key)
```

Raise error on this step when providing bad key.
I know we can catch Error on step when connecting to specific bucket, but I want to catch on previous step.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connect_s3` function does not actually make any requests to S3.  It simply creates and configures the `S3Connection` object and returns it.  If you want to validate the credentials you will have to perform some S3 operation with the connection.  For example, you could try to do a `get_bucket`:

```
import boto

s3 = boto.connect_s3(...)
s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
```

This will actually make a round trip to the S3 service and, if there is a problem with your credentials, you will see an error.

Comment: I know about get_bucket() function, but it gives me error
boto.exception.S3ResponseError. But i want to catch S3ValidationError or something related with access problem.

Comment: If the credentials you provide do not have access to the bucket referenced in the call to ``get_bucket()`` you will receive an ``S3ResponseError``.  The ``reason`` attribute of this exception will contain the string ``"Forbidden"`` and the ``status`` attribute will contain the integer value ``403``.  That should be enough to tell you that the credentials are invalid.

Comment: ok. thanks for your help. Now I can catch this type of specific error.